# Loaded image is lost on fragment change

Tags: android

I have created a simple have app with few fragments settings home and share. At home activity I used to load a image from url from different activity. The image is loading successfully but if change the fragment to settings or share then come back to home the loaded image is lost and the edittext is gone. Below is the home frag code

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment {
    public static Button btn;
    public static EditText userinput;
    public static ImageView wall;
    public static ProgressBar pb;

    public HomePage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragmet

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
        userinput= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText); 
        wall= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        pb= (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SyncImage process= new SyncImage();
                process.execute();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

And here is SyncImage activity code

```
public class SyncImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private String piclink;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL idurl = new URL("mylink.com"+HomePage.userinput.getText());
            HttpURLConnection idConnection= (HttpURLConnection) idurl.openConnection();
            InputStream idStream= idConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader idReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(idStream));
            String line="";
            if (line !=null){
                line=idReader.readLine();
                JSONObject file= new JSONObject(line);
                piclink=file.getString("image");
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        HomePage.wall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        HomePage.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Picasso.get().load(this.piclink).into(HomePage.wall);
        HomePage.pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        HomePage.wall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the code you provided you don't set a image or do anything with your `EditText`.

Comment: That all is been done in SyncImage activity.

Comment: Can you provide that Activity

Comment: That is simple activity, getting image url from my json URL using userinput such as username and loading it into ImageView using Picasso. Nothing more in that.

Comment: "but if change the fragment to settings or share then come back to home the loaded image is lost and the edittext is gone" That is why I want to see the other activity...Is your fragments in a `ViewPager` or how do you display them? With the amout of detail you provided it is impossible to provide a answer.

Comment: Nothing handy in my code fragments are been shown in FrameLayout. And about changing them I am using bottom Navigation. And change them using via transaction.....commit(); method.

Comment: @H.Brooks I've added the SyncImage Activity in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are loading image to your `ImageView wall` in `HomePage` fragment and loose this image after switching fragment to another one, is it? If so you need to keep reference to your image in your `Activity` and load image to `HomeFragment` when it comes back.

P.S. You can do something like this:

- Start your SyncImage `AsyncTask` from `MainActivity`
- Wait for getting `piclink`.
- When `piclink` is received show your `HomeFragment` in `MainActivity` with code:

  ```
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, HomePage.newInstance(piclink)).commit(); //or getSupportFragmentManager()
  ```

where `HomePage` fragment should contain this code:

```
    public class HomePage extends Fragment {
        //Other your stuff...

        private static final String PICLINK = "PICLINK";
        private String piclink;

        public static HomePage newInstance(String piclink) {
            HomePage fragment = new HomePage();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(PICLINK, piclink);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null)
                piclink = getArguments().getString(PICLINK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//To restore piclink after screen rotation
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                piclink = savedInstanceState.getString(PICLINK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {//To save piclink on screen rotation
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString(PICLINK, piclink);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
            //Other views initialization...
            ImageView wall = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            if (piclink != null)
                Picasso.get().load(piclink).into(wall);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: didn't get it sir and I've added the SyncImage Activity in main question.

Comment: `SyncImage` is not an `Activity`, it is an `AsyncTask`. As I see you are getting `URL` of image (piclink) in a background thread and start to load image by Picasso in UI thread. So you can store received `URL` as a class member in your `Activity` (not an `AsyncTask`!) and load image by Picasso in your `HomePage` fragment in `onViewCreated` callback.

Comment: but it will load the image again from url when the fragment view is created. Can we just save the state of image ? And load the image not from url but from the saved state ?

Comment: I am not sure, but Picasso should have an opportunity to do not download image again. You have to make settings to Picasso to keep loaded images in Picasso cache on your device.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never have static views.
2. If there is an orientation state change, you can save the image url in onSaveInstanceState
3. Keep a weak reference to activity/fragment.
4. Use async loader

Comment: can you please share your knowledge by modifying my code ?

Comment: 4. Use [Otto bus](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) instead of async loader.

Comment: @isabsent I would have recommended rx with subscription. But I wanted to avoid external library

Comment: `Bus`'es are much more easy in comparison with `rx` especially for beginners.

Comment: Can you post the activity and the other fragment?